# Add Class on Scroll Issue with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am coding a new site for a client and I want to add a class to a div element once the user reaches 100vh. I have given the body an id of "myBody" and the div element that I want to add the class to an id of "quoteForm" and a class of "quote-form" Here is the html of the page...

```
<body id="myBody">
  <div id="quoteForm" class="quote-form">
    <div id="quoteFormHead"></div>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
      <div id="quoteFormBody">
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="text" name="message_fname" placeholder="Enter your full name here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="email" name="message_email" placeholder="Enter your email address here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="number" name="message_phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here...">
        </div>
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <textarea name="message_msg" placeholder="Details, please! Audience? Word count? Type of document? Tone? Deadlines? Sensitive content?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="quoteFormFooter">
        <div class="formfullwrapper">
          <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Get my free quote">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

as you can see its quite a simple form. Below if the javascript logic I have used to add the class name...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var scrollElement = document.getElementById('myBody');
  var scrollElementPos = scrollElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');

  scrollElement.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    scrollElementPos = scrollElement.scrollTop;
    if(scrollElementPos >= 10){
      form.classList.add("form-fixed");
    } else {
      form.classList.remove("form-fixed");
    }
    console.log(scrollElementPos);
  });
});
```

At present nothing is happening and the class name is not being added to the quote form. Any ideas? Many thanks,

Phillip Dews

Comment: Scrolling usually happens "on" `window`, not the body.

Comment: @CBroe perfect solution thank you for that. added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Yep its the scroll "On" Window. This is what I came up with and it works a dream...

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');
  if (top > 1000) {
    form.classList.add("form-fixed");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("form-fixed");
  }
}
```